# How could I split one row into multiple rows?

Tags: java, sql-server

So, I have this table

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1,2,3 |
| 1,4,5 |

and I want it to be like this

| col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Answer (score 1):

You can split string like this:

```
SELECT 
    value  
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT('a,b,c', ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your delimited data is in a column.  If so, you can use `string_split()` in concert with a `CROSS APPLY`

```
 Select col1=B.value
  From  YourTable A
  Cross Apply string_split(A.col1,',') B
```